# Ajax rendered Partial View Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-8.0

When a razor page contains a property such as "Person1" and that is a complex object that contains sub property's such as "FullName", when you use the asp-for helper tag it has a name of Person1.FullName when rendered, this is the expected name so when the form is posted model binding works.

However in my case the input in inside a partial view
Using the partial helper tag, with the for="Fullname" keeps the "Person1." prefix so everything still ok at this point.

The problem occurs when an ajax call is made via a mvc action that replaces part of the page, now instead of being called "Person1.FullName" the rendered input is just called "FullName".

Is their anyway to render the view from the MVC action, with the prefix of "Person1" on each input?

I have come up with a way to keep the naming correct and therefore the binding still works when the data is posted but it feels very messy.

for reference here my solution which is way too complex

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages;
public class IndexModel : PageModel, IPerson1Wrapper
{

    [BindProperty] public Person Person1 { get; set; } = new();
    [BindProperty] public Person Person2 { get; set; } = new();

    public void OnPost()
    {

    }
}
@page
@model IndexModel

<form method="post">
    <div id="ajaxreplace">
    <partial name="Views/PersonView.cshtml" model="Model" />
    Non Ajax Display
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>

<button onclick="ReloadSection()">Ajax Replace</button>

<script>
    function ReloadSection() {
        $.ajax({ url: '/Home/Index', cache: false, dataType: "html" })
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#ajaxreplace').html(data);       
            });
    }
</script>
```

The the class to hiold the data, plus a interface and a wrapper class to keep name correct

```
public interface IPerson1Wrapper
{
    public Person Person1 { get; set; }
}


public class Person1Wrapper : IPerson1Wrapper
{
    public Person Person1 { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; } = "";
}
```

And finally my partial view with the input

```
@model WebApplication1.Pages.IPerson1Wrapper
@{ Layout = ""; }
<input asp-for="Person1.FullName" />
```

The code just feels wrong, any advice on how to approach this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Although it does not contains the prefix, it also can bind to the backend successfully, assume that you want to distinguish and pass different value to Person1 and Person2, right?

Comment: That's correct, I only want to pass the value to a specific property, missing off the prefix binds to both Person1 & Person2 which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinguish and pass different value to `Person1` and `Person2`, just directly change the model type of your partial view to `IndexModel`:

```
@model WebApplication1.Pages.IndexModel    //change here...
@{
    Layout = "";
}
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<input asp-for="Person1.FullName" />
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Pages;
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

    [BindProperty] public Person Person1 { get; set; } = new();
    [BindProperty] public Person Person2 { get; set; } = new();

    public void OnPost()
    {

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to make this partial in multiple page, you could try to custom tag helper.

1. Custom Input Tag Helper

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

   namespace WebApplication1
   {
       [HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for-prefix")]
       public class InputPrefixTagHelper : TagHelper
       {
           [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for-prefix")]
           public string Prefix { get; set; }

           [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
           public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

           public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
           {
               // Modify the 'name' attribute of the input element
               output.Attributes.SetAttribute("name", $"{Prefix}.{For.Name}");

           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Globally register the custom tag helper in `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` or `Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml`(my assembly name is `WebApplication1` here, you could replace by your onw assembly name). BTW, you can also register it in partial view, then the custom tag helper only works for your current view.

   ```
   @addTagHelper *, WebApplication1
   ```
3. Apply in Razor View

   ```
   @model Person
   @{
       Layout = "";
   }
   @* @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
   @addTagHelper *, WebApplication1 *@

   <input asp-for="FullName" asp-for-prefix="Person1" />
   ```

Comment: Good suggestion, but it wont  work in my case as something I did not mention is the same partial view would be used on multiple pages, that's what I trying to work around with the interface.

Comment: Looks good but not had a chance to try yet

Comment: The standard tag helper will set several things name, id, data-val attributes, with this override the name attribute should be overridden, but the others such as id and data-val  would still be set by the standard helper class. Would that be the case that the other attributes would still be set?

Comment: Hi @Brian, of course, I think you need read and try my answer, I just add the new custom tag helper together with the default `asp-for`, it just change the generated name attribute, the other attribute will not be changed.